# How to synchronize scrolling of a NSScrollView and a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

My app has two main views: a NSTextView subclass within a NSScrollView and a WebView. What the WebView displays is dependent on what the user enters into the text view - so I would like when the user scrolls either the text view or the web view the other scrolls proportionately to it.

I found [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003537-SW5) which mentions how to do it with 2 scroll views. My problem is that WebKit doesn't seem to use normal Scroll views anywhere.

How should I implement this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem to solve perfectly, as it's difficult to know whether the amount of text being edited in your text view corresponds to a similar amount of scrolling in the web view.

However, to answer your question about scroll views in WebView, they are used but as far as I know not documented extensively. You have to take advantage of the fact that you can obtain the scrollview being used, using public API, by asking the appropriate WebView subview for its "enclosingScrollView". Something like this works for me in a WebView where I know that there is only one frame:

```
[[[[myWebView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] enclosingScrollView];
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem except I want to use two WebViews. Would you mind sharing some of the code that you used to set this up, I'm having problems.

Comment: It's hard to know which code to share without knowing more about your troubles. I recommend trying to seize on some little detail of your setup that is confounding to you, and write a separate Stack Overflow question to try to document the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

If they are scrolling proportionately, probably the simplest solution would be to override touches events on your `UIScrollview` and impliment `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` on the `UIWebView` with (js) `window.scroll(x,y)`. However, scrolling from the webView to the textview will require more work. The webView eats touches events, so you would need to

1. create a top level `UIView` or `UIScroll` view which captures the touches and sends them on to both the `scrollView` and the `webView` (via javascript) for ALL touches events, or
2. use a gesture recognizer to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is a Mac related question.